# How to change the size of the overflow menu icon

Tags: android, user-interface, menu, android-actionbar

I have changed the icon for the overflow menu in the action bar, however as a result I get a very small icon (as you can see below), instead I would like it to make it bigger, either by filling the height of the actionBar or by specifying a size (e.g. `50dp`).

However, I cannot seem to find the property that defines the size for it. I have tried to change the size in my style (`50dp` and `150dp`), but it had no effect. You can see my style below:

```
<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_icon</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">"Lala"</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">150dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">150dp</item>
</style>
```

and I call `<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>` in my app theme. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]